# How can i create a Fire in Ignition Gazebo that can be sensoed by thermal Camera ,and Infrared sensor

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress, gazebo-worlds

what are the options we have to create a fire in world .It must  at least look like fire and it must detectable by thermal camera